# Test if python class method is being called by a specific built-in function

Tags: python

Given a python object with custom `__add__` and `__radd__` methods, is it possible to detect if they are being called within the scope of a `sum` built-in function?

naïve example:

```
import inspect
import shlex

class Test:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        curframe = inspect.currentframe()   
        context = inspect.getouterframes(curframe)[1].code_context[0]
        is_summed = 'sum' in list(shlex.shlex(context))
        print('__add__ called from sum():  ', is_summed)       

        try:
            return Test(self.val + other.val)
        except:
            return Test(self.val + other)
    
    def __radd__(self, other):
        curframe = inspect.currentframe()   
        context = inspect.getouterframes(curframe)[1].code_context[0]
        is_summed = 'sum' in list(shlex.shlex(context))
        print('__radd__ called from sum(): ', is_summed)
        
        if other == 0:
            return self
        else:
            return self.__add__(other)
          

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    a = Test(5)
    b = Test(10)

    print('example 1 - plain add: a + b')
    a + b

    print('\nexample 2 - using sum: sum([a, b])')
    sum([a, b])
    
    print('\nexample 3 - (broken) using sum and an add:sum([a, b]) + 5')
    sum([a, b]) + 5
```

Returns:

```
example 1 - plain add: a + b
__add__  called from sum():  False

example 2 - using sum: sum([a, b])
__radd__ called from sum():  True
__add__  called from sum():  True

example 3 - (broken) using sum and an add:sum([a, b]) + 5
__radd__ called from sum():  True
__add__  called from sum():  True
__add__  called from sum():  True # desired result here is False because called outside of "sum"
```

In this example I naïvely return `True` if I detect the term `sum` in the current execution context. This is clearly not enough as it isn't aware of scope, as shows the 3rd example.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way for a class method to know precisely if it is called within the context of a specific built-in function?

Comment: If your goal is to write unit tests, then [`MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) is your friend and can make assertions about which functions are being called. If your goal is to write a function that behaves differently based on its caller, that's really quite unintuitive behavior, so Python's not going to offer an easy gateway to do it.

Comment: The problem is that `context` is the entire statement `sum([a, b]) + 5`. You can't do this by examining statements, you need to use the function call hierarchy.

Comment: @Barmar yes and I can't get `inspect` to give me this hierarchy. If you know how, please consider posting an answer for how to do it. i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I can'f find a way to get that. I looked at the result of `inspect.trace()` but it doesn't show the call to `sum()`.